# Boundaries of testing int and string identities

Tags: python

Integers and Strings are immutable types that can safely be compared for identity.

```
x = 12
x is 12
>>> True
x = "twelve"
x is "twelve"
>>> True
```

Since the `is` operator is comparing memory addresses, this means that Python essentially considers `x` to be the same as `12` and then the same as `"twelve"`. This means you can opt to use `is` to test them rather than the equality operator.

However, I just found out that there's only a specific range where this actually works for integers.

```
x = 256
x is 256
>>> True
x = 257
x is 257
>>> False
x = -5
x is -5
>>> True
x = -6
x is -6
>>> False
id(x)
>>> 35608408L
id(-6)
>>> 35608864L
```

This means that identity only actually works for `-6 < x < 257`. Is there such a limit for strings too that would make identity comparisons unreliable after a certain length? Also is this specific to Python 2.7 or subject to any other variations?

Comment: Never assume that a literal will produce the same object more than once. The fact that the interpreter *may* do this is an optimization, not a language guarantee.

Comment: Read the second answer in the duplicate